# Programatically authenticate AzureAd/OpenId to an MVC controller using C# and get redirect uri

Tags: asp.net-mvc, openid, webclient, azure-active-directory

I have overridden the built in WebClient as below. Then I call it

```
public class HttpWebClient : WebClient
{
    private Uri _responseUri;

    public Uri ResponseUri
    {
        get { return _responseUri; }
    }

    protected override WebResponse GetWebResponse(WebRequest request)
    {
        WebResponse response = base.GetWebResponse(request);

        _responseUri = response.ResponseUri;

        return response;
    }
}
```

Then I consume it like this:

```
using (HttpWebClient client = new HttpWebClient())
{
    client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Authorization] = $"Bearer { _token }";                    
    client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/json";
    client.UploadData(_url, Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_data));

    string queryString = client.ResponseUri.Query.Split('=').Last();
}
```

The response uri comes back with "https://login.microsoftonline" rather than url returned from the MVC controller with a query string, as it is authenticating first with that bearer token using AzureAd/OpenId. If i call it twice it returns the original _url but not the redirected one. If I remove AzureAd authentication it works fine. Is there a way to force the response uri to come back as what the MVC controller sets it to?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you use the 'UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication' and configuring it to use AAD authentication, you can modify the redirect uri by setting Notifications.RedirectToIdentityProvider, something like:

```
Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
{
    RedirectToIdentityProvider = async _ =>
    {
        _.ProtocolMessage.RedirectUri = _.Request.Uri.ToString();
    }
}
```

If you use something else , or maybe I didn't understand your problem - please supply more information